# Changing the width of links/buttons on a Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had a question about the sizing/width of buttons in a Bootstrap Navbar. I tried setting the width of each of them to 50% in my main CSS file so that it would fit in the Nav, and I'm still not having any luck. It seems like there's a lot of space between links which I want to get rid of. Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

HTML

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" bs-navbar>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav nav-justified navbar-right">
            <li data-match-route="/$"><a href="#/" a id="HomeNav">Home</a></li>
            <li data-match-route="/page-one"><a href="#/page-one" id="PageOne">Page One</a></li>
            <li data-match-route="/page-two.*"><a href="#/page-two/sub-a" id="PageTwo">Page Two</a></li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary-outline" href="/users/sign_up" id="SignUp">SIGN UP</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary-outline" href="/users/sign_in" id="SignIn">SIGN IN</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-gray-outline" href="/professionals/sign_in" id="People">People</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
    #HomeNav {

  max-width: 50%;
}
```

(for example)

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: (https://jsfiddle.net/zw6jcv3e/) - it seems as though the Nav links aren't showing up horizontally (like a Navbar normally would) in JSFiddle. I uploaded the bootstrap.min.css too. I did my best.

Comment: Do you want to place two links in each line?

Comment: If it means getting it to look pretty, sure! Thanks

Comment: Can you post a image which is show your desire menu? Check [this](http://postimg.org/image/5zzeon5q9/)

Comment: I'd rather not have something like that, I just simply want to be able to decrease the size of the buttons/items on the navbar so that I can fit them all in. It should be possible, there's all sorts of space between items. Here's a screenshot of what I'm dealing with: http://tinypic.com/r/25q5ait/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, your `<ul>`tag was not set up correctly, change it to this `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">`

HTML:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" bs-navbar>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand navbar-left" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li data-match-route="/$"><a href="#/" a id="HomeNav">Home</a></li>
            <li data-match-route="/page-one"><a href="#/page-one" id="PageOne">Page One</a></li>
            <li data-match-route="/page-two.*"><a href="#/page-two/sub-a" id="PageTwo">Page Two</a></li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary-outline" href="/users/sign_up" id="SignUp">SIGN UP</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary-outline" href="/users/sign_in" id="SignIn">SIGN IN</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-gray-outline" href="/professionals/sign_in" id="People">People</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Demo: [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/OyvGqY/)

Comment: If you want to space them out with this example just increase the padding of the navbar elements.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this well help. If you're trying to have evenly spaced or justified links that you may need to add to.

You can change the display to [table-cell](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) and remove the floats from the navbar.

See working example Snippet.

```css
@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li data-match-route="/$"><a href="#/" a id="HomeNav">Home</a>

        </li>
        <li data-match-route="/page-one"><a href="#/page-one" id="PageOne">Page One</a>

        </li>
        <li data-match-route="/page-two.*"><a href="#/page-two/sub-a" id="PageTwo">Page Two</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="nav-btn btn-secondary-outline" href="/users/sign_up" id="SignUp">SIGN UP</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="nav-btn btn-primary-outline" href="/users/sign_in" id="SignIn">SIGN IN</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="nav-btn btn-gray-outline" href="/professionals/sign_in" id="People">People</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="nav-btn btn-gray-outline" href="/professionals/sign_in" id="People">People</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="nav-btn btn-gray-outline" href="/professionals/sign_in" id="People">People</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a class="nav-btn btn-gray-outline" href="/professionals/sign_in" id="People">People</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```